# Is there a Rails-esque way of structuring PHP projects using Apache?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache

I am just starting to learn PHP development (wordpress specifically) and was wondering if there is a way to structure my PHP projects such that I don't need to create them inside the `/var/www/` folder?

Specifically, I am coming from Ruby on Rails and it was very handy that I just had to type `rails server` into any directory which was initialized with Rails in my system and Rails would automatically associate the correct relative paths.

It is very cumbersome having to sudo each time into the `/var/www/` folder and create the projects there. I would much rather have some sort of directory in my home directory where I can put all my PHP projects into.

I am using the standard LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP).

Comment: What web server are you using? `Apache` ?

Comment: Yes, apologies for not being clear on that point, I have edited my main post.

Comment: There are many PHP application frameworks which layout applications similarly or comparably to Rails, and there's also PHP's own built-in server via `php -S`, which allows you to spin up a web server for testing.

Comment: Have a look at the Laravel framework http://laravel.com/

Comment: With apache you can configure the webroot to be any directory you want, or you can use the userdir module.

Comment: And specifically for the server, [here are the official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Thanks very much for all your responses, the built-in server should be adequate for now, and the Laravel framework looks promising. Michael, you should put your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is quite similar to Rails; I've decided to go ahead and use it.

The command `php artisan serve` is essentially the laravel version of 
`rails server`, and configures the document root to be the current directory, much like `php -S localhost:8000`.